# Symmetric Random Walk with Conditional Probability

Tags: conditional-probability, random-walk

Suppose $(S_n)_{n\geq0}$ is a simple symmetric random walk, 
$$S_n = S_{n-1}+Y_n, S_0 = 0 $$
Where there are $Y_n$ independant variables,
$$P(Y_n=1)=P(Y_n =-1)=\frac{1}{2}, \forall n\geq1$$

How would you calculate,

$$P(S_4 =0|S_2=0,S_1=1)$$
and 
$$P(S_4 =0|Y_2=1,Y_1=1)$$
For,
$$P(S_4 =0|S_2=0,S_1=1) = \frac{P(S_4 =0,S_2=0,S_1=1)}{P(S_2=0,S_1=1)} = \frac{\frac{2}{16}}{\frac{1}{4}}$$
Which I believe represents the events of $P(S_4 =0,S_2=0,S_1=1)$ over the events where $P(S_2=0,S_1=1)$ But im not sure this is the case.

For $P(S_4 =0|Y_2=1,Y_1=1)$ Im not sure where to begin at all, some guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process is Markov.  $P(S_4=0|S_2=0,S_1=1)=P(S_4=0|S_2=0)=1/2$

$P(S_4=0|Y_2=1,Y_1=1)=P(S_4=0|S_2=2)=1/4$